# Apache Reverse Proxy not rewriting URLs the way I expect

Tags: apache, apache2, debian, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am pretty new to Apache and was hoping to setup a reverse proxy to be able to access so the web interfaces of some IP Cameras I have from one site. The basic layout I'm using is below:

```
                             / Cam 1 - 192.168.1.10  
Reverse Proxy - 192.168.1.6 -
                             \ Cam 2 - 192.168.1.11
```

When I click a link it doesn't resolve correctly, the URL should be `http://192.168.1.6/cam1/settings.htm` but it resolves to `http://192.168.1.6/setting.htm`

```
Not Found
The requested URL /setting.htm was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at 192.168.1.6 Port 80
```

My Config is here, I'm using the standard httpd.conf with the proxy and rewrite modules enabled:

```
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *>
        Servername webserver
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteRule ^/cam1/(.*)$ http://192.168.1.10$1 [P]
        RewriteRule ^/cam2/(.*)$ http://192.168.1.11$1 [P]

        ProxyPass /cam1 http://192.168.1.10
        ProxyPassReverse /cam1 http://192.168.1.10
        ProxyPass /cam2 http://192.168.1.11
        ProxyPassReverse /cam2 http://192.168.1.11

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: are you getting any error or can you print the logs here?

Comment: This is whats appearing in the logs... many times over

[Mon Oct 15 10:14:32 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.112] File does not exist: /var/www/lang, referer: http://192.168.1.6/controlmenu.htm

[Mon Oct 15 10:14:32 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.112] File does not exist: /var/www/jpg, referer: http://192.168.1.6/main.htm

[Mon Oct 15 10:14:32 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.112] File does not exist: /var/www/style, referer: http://192.168.1.6/controlmenu.htm

Answer (score 0):

In logs you can clearly see that there are some files missing like **File does not exist: /var/www/jpg** and **/var/www/lang** so may be this is the reason for your storage issue.I bet you that you missed some configuration while server OR your server msy corrupt these files while running due to some other files.I suggest you to fresh download and then reinstall it.

Comment: If i type the full path http//192.168.1.6/cam1/.../page.htm it resolves but if i go to http://192.168.1.6/cam1 and click a link that is just referenced as page.htm then i get the errors. Should the reverse proxy take care of the the 'non full path' links and redirect it to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

For future users:

cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@work.com.br

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from 192.168.5.25
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPass               /cameras/               http://192.168.5.6/
    ProxyPassReverse        /cameras/               http://192.168.5.6/
```